# form validation fails some times and shows value erorr

Tags: django, python-3.x

Sometimes form is validating but sometimes form is not validating and shows value error

**views.py**

```
def hai(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        obj1 = hello(request.FILES, request.POST)
        if obj1.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse("success")
```

does form need to be cleaned every time submiting?

**forms.py**

```
class hello(forms.Form):
    uname = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = forms.FileField()
```

**template**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action= {% url 'hai' %} method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data ">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
      <label for="" class="label">Pick-up date</label>
      <input type="text" name="uname" class="form-control"
             placeholder="Date">
    </div><br>
    <div class="form-group ml-2">
      <label for="" class="label">Drop-off date</label>
      <input type="file" name="img" class="form-control"
             placeholder="Date">
    </div><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Book Now" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px4">
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the error:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that you're **not returning** an `HttpResponse` (or subclass) when your form is not valid.

Comment: sorry i didnt understand , iam new to this

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you should *always* return `HttpResponse` (or subclass), whether yourr form is valid or not; So basically you should have:

```
def hai(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        obj1 = hello(request.FILES, request.POST)
        if obj1.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse("success")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("error")
```

or you can send back the form with it's errors in the template, if you wish.

Comment: @sivaprasad Are you using the same `url` for both `GET` and `POST` request? Please also include your view for the `GET` request, if it's different from this one.

Comment: this is my url                                                                             
    path('home/', home, name='home'),
    path('hai/', hai, name='hai'),

Comment: sir iam trying to write in to database using form but i cant  do because of  the error , but the same code i had alredy used and succeeded on another project but this time the code fails

Comment: @sivaprasad Try inspecting the error: add `print(obj1.errors)` in your view to find what's wrong.

Comment: if request.method == 'POST':
        obj1 = hello(request.FILES, request.POST)
        if obj1.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse("ok")
        else:
            print(obj1.errors)    is this is correct

Comment: the same error that i have shown above in the question sir